# Django не принимает мой кастомный язык?

Tags: django

**вот** мой код в сеттингсе:

```
gettext_noop = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = [
    ('ru', _('Русский')),
    # ('en', _('English')),
    ('uzb', _('Ўзбекча')),
    ('uz', _("O'zbekcha")),
]

EXTRA_LANGUAGE = {
    'uzb': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'uzb',
        'name': 'Ўзбек',
        'name_local': 'Ўзбекча'
    }
}

django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANGUAGE)
```

Зачем-то (на мой взгляд) i18n не принимает кодовый язык 'uzb'. Почему? Или я что-то упустил? Если я выбираю язык кроме 'uzb', url изменится (т.е. http://127.0.0.1:8000/uz/administrator/ или http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/administrator/ т.п.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38528364/5909792 ?

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Помогло? :) Сделайте тогда сами ответ с решением :)

Comment: @gil9red непонятно что это должно изменить, если Django всё равно автоматически смотрит папки locale в подключенных Django-приложениях